# Using trees generated by rpart in R to classify a new observation

Tags: r, decision-tree, pattern-recognition

Say I use the rpart function in R which fits a classification tree to a dataset. How do I then use this tree to classify a new object?

Answer (score 1):

```
?predict.rpart # ................
```

Probably (only a guess in the absence of an R object.)

```
predict(rtree, type = "class")
```